# IOS 10 and the deferred location update

Tags: swift, background, ios10, core-location, deferred

several people reported the issue with the deferred location updates under IOS 10. I also struggle with this issue and did some intensive testing.

Looking at this results I can not imagine that Apples ignores such a major malfunction for more than a year (first reports I'm aware of, are from March / April 2016). AND there only a few developers reporting that issue.

So I hope there is some kind of "magic trick" to get that feature up an running.

The app worked fine with deferred updates under IOS 9. I did no major change on code level. I do all the things you have to do, read (I think almost all) available documents, went through numerous tutorials, bought several books ... I pretty sure I do everything a programmer has to do, to get that feature up and running...

BUT:

On all my physical test devices (iPhone 5s, iPad mini 4, iPhone SE, iPhone 7; all running IOS 10.3.x) I got a "false" if I call CLLocationManager.deferredLocationUpdatesAvailable(). Always, immediately.

I do all my testing on walks, runs and drives in the real world (not on simulator). in city areas, forests, etc.

My app is allowed to run in the background. It does that very fine. It is restarted in the background with visits and region boundary crossing. All work perfect.

If I start the app in foreground, start the location updates and than switch it to background, it runs (as expected) for a long time, all location updates were received .. all fine.

If the app ist restarted in the background it runs for the famous 180 secs. Also fine... BUT: within that 180 secs the location updates stopped from one second to the other,

- the "remaining time" (UIApplication.shared.backgroundTimeRemaining)
  freezes(!)
- The accuracy of the received location updates is almost always at +/-
  5 meters (GPS hardware is obviously up and running)
- several minutes(!) later the location updates gets restarted (in the
  background)
- The remaining time continuous exactly at the freezed time (e.g. if it
  was 170 sec left, it is than 169 sec left)
- the accuracy of the than incoming first updates are terrible (+/- 3
  km) (so I think IOS switched to cell tower until GPS hardware is
  restarted) .. in general it looks like SignificantLocationChanges had
  fired ... interesting I switched them OFF
- after 10 seconds all is OK (accuracy getting better and better and is
  finally again at +/- 5 m)

I call that "drop outs".

So far so bad...

BUT: If I use the device at the same time e.g. to listen to podcasts or music, this "drop outs" do not happen.

So my theory: the drop outs start when the device enters some kind of a "low power mode". That was exactly the time when under IOS 9 the deferred location updates start working. I assume that "behind the scene" the deferred location update is still working.. but unfortunately this deferred locations do not find a way to the "didUpdateLocation:" call back - maybe because "something" in IOS does not allow that (overlaying flags or what ever)

I tried several things to get over this hurdles

- I ignored the result of CLLocationManager.deferredLocationUpdatesAvailable  and called
  "myLocationManager!.allowDeferredLocationUpdates(untilTraveled:
  CLLocationDistanceMax, timeout: CLTimeIntervalMax)" every callback of
  "didUpdateLocations:" (getting a ".deferredFailed" error code every
  time)
- I set all relevant parameters at each call of didUpdateLocations:
- I "played" with the "activityType", set it the appropriate according 
  to the motion status (walk, run, drive, stationary)
- I even build a version with four parallel runLoops (not just "main"),
  each hosting a separate locationManager with different activityType
  settings (yes, it is possible (took me two das to find out how ;-)), 
  yes there are some small differences, but nothing significant)

SO: If someone has some kind of hint ... PLEASE give me a that ...

Does anybody has deferred updates working under IOS 10.x?

And before someone asks, the parameter set: (the plist keys are also set, user gave authorization for "always use")

```
myLocationManager!.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
myLocationManager!.stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
myLocationManager!.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
myLocationManager!.headingFilter = kCLHeadingFilterNone
myLocationManager!.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
myLocationManager!.activityType = CLActivityType.fitness (or other)
myLocationManager!.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
```

** *please help !!!* **

Comment: I don't understand why this is not a complete duplicate of the existing questions on this topic. `deferredLocationUpdatesAvailable` is never `true`, and, although we may be able to get updates every second in the background, we never in fact defer. That's just a fact. Asking about it again contributes nothing new. What worked in iOS 9 doesn't work in iOS 10. The end (until they fix it). File a bug report with Apple, the more the merrier! But don't duplicate this question uselessly.

Comment: Yes, I'm fully aware of these questions. My Problem is something else... I found a question in the apple developer comunity. Someone who has a problem with location updates under IOS10 AND saying that deferred updates works fine !!!! ... And: in one of the threads you mentioned someone got a "works as desinged" from Apple.... AND: I can not believe, that Apple ignores a malfunction of one of the core features of an important framework for more than a year. ... So there must be SOME way to get it work... and as old questions get out of scope, I renew this problem with this question.

Comment: _AND: I can not believe, that Apple ignores a malfunction of one of the core features of an important framework for more than a year_ I've been programming iOS since 3.2 and I've seen Apple create breakage that lasted much longer than that. And old questions don't get out of scope, they get returned to and answered. If there were a solution we'd know it by now.

Comment: OK, maybe I'm too naive on that ;-) ... anyway, my concerns are based on that two statements "works as designed" and "deferred updates working well" which I found... and I know that the questions stay in that database .. my observation is, that the answers come in fast (hours, days) or very, very late. I think this is simply that you answer question immediately when you saw them popping up, or much later when you found them by active research

Comment: @Hardy_Germany were you able to find a solution by now?

Comment: no, i just ignore the functionality now. Even in IOS 11 it is still not working. My app would work with deferred updates, if the device signals that it is available, but my app design does not need this possibilty anymore. It‘s a shame, but you can‘t ignore the facts.